# Tableau - Average of Ranking based on Average

Tags: aggregate-functions, tableau-api, rank, level-of-detail

For a certain data range, for a specific dimension, I need to calculate the average value of a daily rank based on the average value.

First of all this is the starting point:
[image]

This is quite simple and for each day and category I get the AVG(value) and the Ranke based on that AVG(Value) computed using Category.

Now what I need is "just" a table with one row for each Category with the average value of that rank for the overall period.

Something like this:

```
Category         Global Rank
A (blue)            1,6             (1+3+1+1+1+3)/6
B (orange)          2,3             (3+2+3+2+2+2)/6
C (red)             2,0             (2+1+2+3+3+1)/6
```

I tried using the LOD but it's not possble using rank table calculation inside them so I'm wondering if I'm missing anything or if it's even possible in Tableau.

Please find attached the twbx with the raw data [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08158319278812299699):

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at window_avg() https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html

Comment: Take new sheet and swap Day of date and category

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you